# Python Telebot Error code: 401

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

```
2021-01-05 17:01:10,099 (__init__.py:489 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
```

Выдает ошибку. Сам код я оставил до минимума -

```
import telebot
token="здесь корректный токен"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: данная ошибка чаще всего возникает при использовании некорректного токена, вы можете получить новый токен для существующего бота у `BotFather`

Comment: @Violet я это уже делал. Пришлось найти другую библиотеку - с ней получилось, но там нет функции пересылки сообщений (я не нашел, новая библиотека - python-telegram-bot)